# Explore File Table Directory is diasabled

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I want to open up File Table content through SQL Server Management Studio I right click on the database and try to click on **Explore File Table Directory**.
But it's not enabled as you see on the image.

What's wrong with this? Any suggestion to enable this?

[image: Attached Image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the filestream(NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS) the FULL access which can be done through SSMS interface or executing a query:

*Using interface:*
Right click on your database and select properties, in the just opened dialog select `Options` then in the FileStream section, give it a directory name and for the `NON_TRANSACTED ACCESS` select `Full` just like following [image]

Using Query:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDB
SET FILESTREAM(NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS=FULL, DIRECTORY_NAME='MyDBFileStream')
```

If the query execution took longer than it is expected, try to stop applications which are using the database, in my case it was because of IIS, I just stoped the IIS Service.

If you encounter an error like following:

```
FILESTREAM DIRECTORY_NAME 'MyDBFileStream' attempting to be set on database 'MyDB' is not unique in this SQL Server instance. Provide a unique value for the database option FILESTREAM DIRECTORY_NAME to enable non-transacted access.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
```

It's because you have another database with the same directory name, try to change one of them or just simply change the associated filestream directory name of the current database to something else.